# Shared memory changes aren't visible in different process

Tags: windows, assembly, memory

I have a problem. As far as I know, processes in Windows share dynamic-linked libraries among each other, allowing only one instance of every library to exist at once in the memory. Knowing that, I wrote a small program in C, which can change some data in this shared section. In my example, I chose to change the beginning of MessageBoxW function. This is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define SIZE 12 // size of JMP byte array defined below

int WINAPI CustomMessageBoxW(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);

void BeginRedirect(LPVOID);

// JMP bytes translated to assembly (x64):
//      mov rax, 0x1234567890ABCDEF     - this value will be changed to newFunction address, in BeginRedirect procedure
//      jmp rax                         - jump to newFunction

BYTE JMP[SIZE] = { 0x48, 0xB8, 0xEF, 0xCD, 0xAB, 0x90, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12, 0xFF, 0xE0 };
DWORD oldProtect, myProtect = PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE;

int main()
{
    printf("MessageBoxW address: %p\n", MessageBoxW);
    printf("redirect? ");
    char res[4];
    scanf_s("%4s", res, _countof(res));
    if (strcmp(res, "yes") == 0) // redirect
    {
        printf("redirecting...\n");
        BeginRedirect(MessageBoxW, CustomMessageBoxW);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, L"This is original MessageBoxW", L"Caption", MB_OKCANCEL);
        printf("MessageBoxW address: %p\nBytes:\n", MessageBoxW);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            printf("0x%hhX ", *((char*)MessageBoxW + i));
        }
        puts("\n");
        SleepEx(1000, FALSE);
    }
}

void BeginRedirect(LPVOID oldFunction, LPVOID newFunction)
{
    BYTE tempJMP[SIZE];
    memcpy(tempJMP, JMP, SIZE);

    BOOL result = VirtualProtect(oldFunction, SIZE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
    printf("\tVirtualProtect result: %u\n", result);

    memcpy(tempJMP + 2, &newFunction, 8); // change the basic 0x1234... address to the actual function address
    memcpy(oldFunction, tempJMP, SIZE);

    result = VirtualProtect(oldFunction, SIZE, oldProtect, &myProtect);
    printf("\tVirtualProtect result: %u\n", result);
}

int WINAPI CustomMessageBoxW(HWND hWnd, LPCWSTR lpText, LPCWSTR lpCaption, UINT uiType)
{
    printf("MyMessageBoxW: Custom message\n");
}
```

The program allows to choose if I want to redirect the function in the current instance of the program. Here comes the interesting part.

I run a first instance. When asked if to redirect, I type "yes", so the program does. **It changes the beginning code of MessageBoxW, so that it points to my CustomMessageBoxW**. Then, in the while loop, the program executes MessageBoxW every second and outputs some debugging information (first 20 bytes of the function). In this instance, the redirection works properly and instead of popup, the program outputs "MyMessageBoxW: Custom message" every second (as expected in CustomMessageBoxW)

Then, I run the second instance of the program (**the first instance still executes!**). Now, I decide not to redirect the function (type anything apart from "yes"). From the information printed by both instances about their MessageBoxW addresses, I can see that they're clearly **identical**. At that point, I thought that if the addresses are the same (both instances share one instance of user32.dll which contains MessageBoxW), then the second instance which didn't modify the MessageBoxW function itself will still attempt to execute the CustomMessageBoxW, which will probably result in memory access violation. But no. It turns out that the second instance works just fine and pops up a standard Windows message box, while the first instance (which still runs) still executes the redirected function (remember that in both program instances, the addresses of MessageBoxW are the same). Apart from that, the bytes outputed by

```
printf("MessageBoxW address: %p\nBytes:\n", MessageBoxW);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    printf("0x%hhX ", *((char*)MessageBoxW + i));
}
```

are completely different in both instances, while the function address is still the same.

I even decided to debug both instances at the same time using WinDbg, and it also showed that both instances stored different values under the same address. I'd really appreciate it if someone figured out what is actually going round here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but normally shared libraries are loaded with [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write), so that each process effectively has its own independent copy.  Normally you do not write to the code in the DLL, so COW never occurs and the code remains shared, and maybe that's what you meant by "only one instance exists in memory".  But it would be horrible if one process was able to change the code that another process was executing, unless the two processes had explicitly set this up between them.

Comment: And just because the two *virtual* addresses are the same, does not mean the contents are identical.  Each process has its own virtual address space, so it's entirely possible for the same virtual address to map to different physical memory in different processes.

Comment: I believe that the opposite is also true: different virtual addresses in two processes may point to the same physical memory (e.g. in the case of a shared dll that hasn't been written to).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Yes, with ASLR, it's normal for different processes to map the same physical pages read-only at different virtual addresses.  (Or in fact any shared-memory can be at different addresses.  That's why it's important that C++11 `std::atomic` is supposed to be "address-free" when `is_lock_free()` is true, so it's usable in shared memory because it doesn't contain its own address or depend on it.)

Comment: i knew about this thing in linux where different processes map different physical addresses to the same virtual address, but i didnt know that it could exist in windows... is it actually in windows by default?